# Updated netbeans to 1.4 from 1.3 and now my tiff image methods dont seem to work

Tags: java, exception, netbeans

Prior to updating my netbeans IDE to 1.4, I was using the 1.3 version and I was working on a java app that could compress multi-page tiff images. One of the methods in that project was a method to get the bit depth of the image using the ImageIO methods. The method was as follows:

```
    private synchronized void setBitDepth()
    {
       if(this.getImageInputStream() == null)
       {
           System.out.println("ImageInputStreamFailure");
       }
       try
       {
           //System.out.println("Path: " + this.testTiff);
           ImageInputStream testInStream = ImageIO.createImageInputStream(new File(this.testTiff)); //test
           Iterator<ImageReader> readers = ImageIO.getImageReaders(testInStream);
           ImageReader reader;
           if(!readers.hasNext())
           {
               throw new IOException("Cant read format...");
           }
           else
           {
               reader = readers.next();
           }
           reader.setInput(this.getImageInputStream(), true, true);
           this.bitDepth = reader.getImageTypes(0).next().getColorModel().getPixelSize();
           reader.dispose();
       }
       catch(IOException e)
       {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }

    }
```

This method worked fine in the 1.3 IDE, but as soon as I updated to 1.4 this method always throws the `"Cant read format..."` exception. What would cause this?

Comment: Do you mean NetBeans 7.4 and 7.3?  1.4 and 1.3 are quite old versions, if they existed at all.

Comment: Support for TIFF and JPEG2000 is added to Java by copying the Java Advanced ImageIO JAR file (jai_imageio.jar, if I remember correctly) to JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/ext.  Perhaps there's more than one Java installation on your machine, the old version of NetBeans picked up one that had this JAR in and the new version of NetBeans is picking up a different JAVA_HOME that doesn't have this JAR?